# aws-sdk (v2) safe_define_method error raised

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk

I am trying to create an AWS IAM client in my Ruby (2.2.) script

```
@iam = Aws::IAM::Client.new(
  access_key_id: Aws.config[:credentials][:access_key_id],
  secret_access_key: Aws.config[:credentials][:secret_access_key],
  region: Aws.config[:region])
```

It raises the error :

```
*** Aws::Resources::Errors::DefinitionError 
Exception: unable to define method #create_group, method already exists
```

Aws.config is already set from a profile stored in my config file ( ~/.aws/config)

```
    {:region=>"eu-central-1", :credentials=>   
       {:access_key_id=>"**___my_accesss_id__**",
        :secret_access_key=>"**__my_secret_access_key___**"}}
```

what could be wrong ?

Update : If I use the aws-sdk v1 version .. no issue :
@IAM = AWS::IAM.new

seems to be an error in v2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are using a version of the SDK that had an error in the IAM resource definition model. If you update to a more recent version of the gem. This error should be gone.

Comment: Thanks Trevor for your feedback. I'm using the latest version of the sdk : v2aws-sdk-resources (2.0.32)... other was services can be accessed :
 s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(credentials: credentials)
#<Aws::S3::Client>
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(region:'us-west-2')
#<Aws::EC2::Client>
I only get this error with the IAM service ...

Comment: sory .. you put me on the tracks....   one of my lib scripts was still calling the v1 version ...
 def create_group(name, policy_json, policy_name, iam=nil)
      iam ||= AWS::IAM.new